MeiliSearchApiError: Stale file handle (os error 116)
I am using meilisearch meilisearch:v1.4.0 as the fulltext search engine, today when I invoke the the index api, shows error like this:
│ node:internal/process/promises:279
│             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
│             ^
│
│ MeiliSearchApiError: Stale file handle (os error 116)
│     at /home/node/app/node_modules/meilisearch/dist/bundles/meilisearch.cjs.js:366:19
│     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
│     at fulfilled (/home/node/app/node_modules/meilisearch/dist/bundles/meilisearch.cjs.js:298:58)
│     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
│   code: 'internal',
│   type: 'internal',
│   link: 'https://docs.meilisearch.com/errors#internal',
│   httpStatus: 500
│ }

this is the nodejs(v18.x) client code "meilisearch": "^0.35.0" look like:
const { MeiliSearch } = require('meilisearch')
var log4js = require('log4js')
var logger = log4js.getLogger()
logger.level = 'warn'

const updateFullsearch = async (file) => {
  try {
    const masterKey = process.env.MEILI_MASTER_KEY
    let option = {
      primaryKey: 'file_id'
    }
    const client = new MeiliSearch({
      host: 'http://meilisearch.reddwarf-toolbox.svc.cluster.local:7700',
      apiKey: masterKey
    })
    let clientIdx = client.index('files')
    clientIdx.addDocuments([file], option)
      .then((res) => {})
    clientIdx.updateFilterableAttributes(['name', 'project_id'])
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('Failed to sync file index', err)
  }
}
module.exports = {
  updateFullsearch
}

Am I missing something? does anyone facing the similiar issue?
